# React Native TextInput - cannot get/access value in onSubmitEditing handler (especially iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, event-handling, onsubmit

This must be a simple question that I have not been able to find the answer to:

The below code works in React-native for Web, as you would expect in React.js... but it does ***NOT*** work for in iOS

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

const App = (props) =>{

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const onChangeText (text) => {
      setInput(text)
    }  
    const onSubmitted (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)   // <== this does not work (is undefined)
    } 
    ...
    //more code here
    ... 
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        onSubmitEditing={onSubmitted}
        value={input}   
      />
    );
};
export default App;
```

I've tried option #2 - mimicking examples for how the onChangeEvent should work/be implemented:

```
    const onSubmitted (text) => {
        console.log(text)   // <== this does not work EITHER (is undefined)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after lots and lots of googling...

I found that the correct variable that is passed from the `onSubmittedEditing` event is **not** an `event` object and **not even** a simple `text` string as in the case of the `onChangeText` event.  But rather it's a `value` object with a `nativeEvent` property.  This object of type `nativeEvent` in turn contains a `text` property/variable which contains the actual text/value from the `TextInput` field/control.

Now if you're developing for the web, you'll see that this `nativeEvent` has a whole bunch of properties including the familiar web/HTML `target` property, which then contains a `value` property ==>  ***BUT, THIS MIGHT CONFUSE YOU AS IT DID ME*** ==> because on other platforms (I can only speak definitively right now about **ios**) the `value` object has only 3 properties and corresponding values (the below is an example if you/the user entered "3" as the value in the `textInput` control:

```
value: {
"eventCount": 1, 
"target": 1855, 
"text": "3"
}
```

so that makes the following the correct syntax for your react-native code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const App = (props) =>{

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const onChangeText (text) => {
      setInput(text)
    }  
    const onSubmitted (value) => {
        console.log(value.nativeEvent.text)   // <== this does not work (is undefined)
    } 
    ...
    //more code here
    ... 
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        onSubmitEditing={onSubmitted}
        value={input}   
      />
    );
};
export default App;
```